# Get ID and protein sequences in biopython

Tags: python, sequence, biopython, fasta

I have this code.

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("aminoacids.txt", "fasta"):

print(seq_record.id)

print(repr(seq_record.seq))
```

Output:

```
NP_414584.1

Seq('MNTFSQVWVFSDTPSRLPELMNGAQALANQINTFVLNDADGAQAIQLGANHVWK...LAR')

NP_414563.1

Seq('MASVSISCPSCSATDGVVRNGKSTAGHQRYLCSHCRKTWQLQFTYTASQPGTHQ...RSR')

NP_414564.1

Seq('MANIKSAKKRAIQSEKARKHNASRRSMMRTFIKKVYAAIEAGDKAAAQKAFNEM...KLA')

NP_414565.1

Seq('MCRHSLRSDGAGFYQLAGCEYSFSAIKIAAGGQFLPVICAMAMKSHFFLISVLN...SLF')

NP_414566.1

Seq('MKLIRGIHNLSQAPQEGCVLTIGNFDGVHRGHRALLQGLQEEGRKRNLPVMVML...KPA')
```

Problem: I should get the ID and the full sequence without "Seq" at the beggining and in just one string.
Something like this:

```
NP_414584.1
MNTFSQVWVFSDTPSRLPELMNGAQALANQINTFVLNDADGAQAIQLGANHVWKLNGKPDDRMIEDYAGVMADTIRQHGADGLVLLPNTRRGKLLAAKLGYRLKAAVSNDASTVSVQDGKATVKHMVYGGLAIGEERIATPYAVLTISSGTFDAAQPDASRTGETHTVEWQAPAVAITRTATQARQSNSVDLDKARLVVSVGRGIGSKENIALAEQLCKAIGAELACSRPVAENEKWMEHERYVGISNLMLKPELYLAVGISGQIQHMVGANASQTIFAI NKDKNAPIFQYADYGIVGDAVKILPALTAALAR
```

How can I get this output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`repr` is not designed for doing final output.  It's essentially a debug tool.  What you have is a `Seq` object.  You probably need to be doing:

```
print(seq_record.seq)
```

which uses the `str` method.